# What is seasonality in PROC AUTOREG Durbin Watson Test in SAS?

Tags: math, statistics, sas, correlation

I want to understand how seasonality for the Durbin Watson Test is defined. If I understand it correctly, the option DW is used for the number of seasons in my data. How can I generally check how many seasons there are? This is my plotted data (but I want to understand how it works for other data, too):
[image: "Tag" = Day, "Mittelwert" = Average Temperature]

This is where I got my information from: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/etsug/etsug_autoreg_gettingstarted07.htm

My data consists of average air temperature per day.

Why do I even need higher-order statistics?